# Breakpoints Not Highlighting Line

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I'm suddenly running into an odd problem with breakpoints in Visual Studio 2019 (this is for a C# solution).

Yesterday setting a breakpoint highlighted the entire source code line in the editor.

Today it only sets the red circle in the left-hand margin.

Something has changed but I have no idea what. How do I revert to the earlier behavior?

Comment: That is the way it is supposed to work.  You'll get the line highlighted when code execution actually lands on the breakpoint.

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear: the highlighting I was referring to was the way the breakpoint line's background color in the source code window is red (at least on my system). The problem I was running into was that the background color had reverted to the default/normal color (white on my system).

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what happened but running the VS Installer and telling it to Modify the setup -- and then not making any changes -- fixed the problem.

Obviously something got messed up somewhere and I'd still love to know what happened. But the problem is gone...for now.